# jquery accordion sliding down too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got an accordion that when you click on each button it expands out and displays further info. It works fine, however each time i click each button to expand it, the box seems to slide up and down like 7/8 times before displaying the content box. I would only ideally like it slide up and down twice or 3 times max before showing the full content. How would be the best way to achieve this.

HTML:

```
  <div id="ss_menu">
    <h3><b>Winning Ways</b></h3>
  <div class="ss_button">1990-1991</div>
  <div class="ss_content">1st NBA Title<br />
  61 Wins 21 Losses<br />MVP Michael Jordan<br />
  Defeated LA Lakers<br /></div>
  <div class="ss_button">1991-1992</div>
  <div class="ss_content">Repeat Champions<br />
  67 Wins 15 Losses<br />MVP Michael Jordan<br />
  <div class="ss_button">1992-1993</div>
  <div class="ss_content">ThreePeat Champions<br />57 Wins 25 Losses<br />
  MVP Michael Jordan<br />Defeated Phoenix Suns<br /></div>
  <div class="ss_button">1995-1996</div>
  <div class="ss_content">1st NBA Title in 3 years<br />
  72 Wins 10 Losses<b>(NBA history)</b><br />MVP Michael Jordan<br />   
  <b>*Michael Jordan came back from retirement!</b><br />Defeated LA 
  Lakers<br /></div> <div class="ss_button">1996-1997</div>
  <div class="ss_content">2nd Repeat<br />69 Wins 13 Losses<br />
  MVP Michael Jordan<br />Defeated Utah Jazz<br /></div>
 <div class="ss_button">1997-1998</div> <div class="ss_content">
  2nd ThreePeat<br />62 Wins 20 Losses<br />MVP Michael Jordan<br />
  Defeated Utah Jazz<br /></div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#ss_menu h3{ 
color: white; 
}

#ss_menu { 
width: 200px; 
position:absolute;
right:10px; 
top:825px;
z-index:1
}

.ss_button { 
background-color: black;
border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 10px;
color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

.ss_content {
background-color: #EFEFEF;
display: none;
padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;

}
```

JS:

```
 jQuery(function () {
 jQuery('.ss_button').on('click', function () {
    jQuery('.ss_content').slideUp('fast');
    jQuery(this).next('.ss_content').slideDown('fast');
});
});
```

Comment: Please, check my answer, I'm quite sure that it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a **br** instead of **div** closure in the contents of 1991-1992.
The problem is always **Michael Jordan**. Check **https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/jbz6dxbp/** your code works good. It's weird, but works.

```
  <div class="ss_button">1991-1992</div>
  <div class="ss_content">Repeat Champions<br />
   67 Wins 15 Losses<br />MVP Michael Jordan
  </div>
```

Comment: your JSfiddle is exactly what i want it to do, but when i follow your advice, and put it on my own IDE its still sliding up and down like 7 times

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you are attaching the event handler more than once? (because window resizing handling, ajax loadding & adding elements or something similar)
A simple test: add a "processed" class to your ".ss_buttons" just after attaching the click, and use as selector ".ss_button:not(.processed)" .

```
jQuery(function () {
 jQuery('.ss_button:not(.processed)').on('click', function () {
    jQuery('.ss_content').slideUp('fast');
    jQuery(this).next('.ss_content').slideDown('fast');
 });
 jQuery('.ss_button:not(.processed)').addClass('processed')
});
```

EDIT: and the html have also a problem as vixed pointed:

```
<div id="ss_menu">

 <h3><b>Winning Ways</b></h3>

 <div class="ss_button">1990-1991</div>
  <div class="ss_content">
    1st NBA Title<br />
    61 Wins 21 Losses<br />MVP Michael Jordan<br />
    Defeated LA Lakers<br />
  </div>

 <div class="ss_button">1991-1992</div>
  <div class="ss_content">
    Repeat Champions<br />
    67 Wins 15 Losses<br />
    MVP Michael Jordan<br />
 ***** <-- Should'nt be here a "</div>"

 <div class="ss_button">1992-1993</div>
  <div class="ss_content">
    ThreePeat Champions<br />

 ...

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is works fine. It's weird problem. You could use preventDefault() function. See if that works.

```
    jQuery('.ss_button').on('click', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.ss_content').slideUp('fast');
    jQuery(this).next('.ss_content').slideDown('fast');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use smooth accordion as explained here in this link.

https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Including jquery UI into the project is unnecessary.